# На хостинге не работает //IGNORE в iconv, строка на выходе обрезается - как исправить?

Tags: php, utf-8, cp1251, iconv

Меняю кодировку у большого текста (2-3Мб):

```
$content = iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251', $content);
```

в итоге текст обрезался постоянно на определенном месте, узнал про IGNORE, переписал в:

```
$content = iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251//IGNORE', $content);
```

на домашнем сервере заработала, на хостинге нет.

В чём может быть проблема? Или если не разбираться как её можно обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему использованием другой функции:mb_convert_encoding

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content,  'CP1251', 'UTF-8');
```